# Utilizar o Signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Bom estou começando a me aventurar no `Signalr`. Resolvi seguir este [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

Bom depois de fazer todos os passos, ao executar o projeto me apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Unhandled exception at line 35, column 13 in
>   http:// localhost:54051/Index.html
>
> 0x800a138f - Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: Não é possível
>   obter a propriedade 'client' de referência indefinida ou nula

Na seguinte parte:

```
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        // Html encode display name and message. 
        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
        var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
        // Add the message to the page. 
        $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
            + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
    };
```

Index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message. 
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ChatHub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro significa que `chat` está vindo nulo nesta atribuição:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
```

Ao que tudo indica, você não fez o passo 8 do tutorial, que é registrar no `Global.asax`, no evento `Application_Start`, o seguinte:

```
// Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito, só que estava na ultima linha troquei a ordem e deu certo!